# Вложенный SQl запрос, как правильно составить?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Задача: 
Получить количество лайков и подписок через один запрос. 
Подписки и лайки хранятся в отношении многие к многим.

Сделал отдельные запросы, которые получают кол-во лайков и подписок отдельно. 
Для лайков получилось так:

```
select count(user_article_likes.article_id) as likes from `articles` inner join `user_article_likes` on `user_article_likes`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id` group by `articles`.`id`;
```

Для подписок получилось так:

```
select count(subscribed_user_articles.article_id) as subscribed from `articles` inner join `subscribed_user_articles` on `subscribed_user_articles`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id` group by `articles`.`id`;
```

Из всего этого хочу получить всего лишь один запрос с выводом: 
Article
- кол-во лайков
- кол-во подписок
(ну и так на каждой статье)

Пробовал так:

```
SELECT COUNT(subscribed_user_articles.article_id) AS subscribed, COUNT(user_article_likes.article_id) AS likes FROM `articles`
INNER JOIN `subscribed_user_articles` ON `subscribed_user_articles`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id`
INNER JOIN `user_articles_likes` ON `user_articles_likes`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id`
GROUP BY `articles`.`id`
```

И так:

```
select 
articles.id,
count(distinct user_article_likes.article_id),
count(distinct subscribed_user_articles.article_id)
from articles
left join  user_article_likes on user_article_likes.article_id = articles.id
left join subscribed_user_articles on subscribed_user_articles.article_id = articles.id
group by articles.id
```

Все не то. Либо у лайков и подписок одно и тоже значение(чего быть не может, ибо показывает кол-во записей больше чем есть в БД).

Какие есть идеи? Мысли? Куда смотреть и что почитать?

Comment: count(distinct user_article_likes.article_id), - здесь вы считаете количество уникальных статей в группе. Поскольку вы группируете по статье, то должны получить 1. Считать нужно уникальные лайки (ну, или уникальных пользователей, которые лайкнули).

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko, спасибо большое, вы правы, заработало!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой и понятный подход будет выглядеть так:

```
select articles.id,
(select count(user_article_likes.article_id) from user_article_likes where user_article_likes.article_id = articles.id) AS likes 
(select count(subscribed_user_articles.article_id) from subscribed_user_articles where subscribed_user_articles.article_id = articles.id) as subscriptions
from articles
order by articles.id
```

Ваши запросы не работают потому как когда вы создаете join, в результирующей таблице у вас получается столько строчек сколько в двух таблицах вместе взятых. Отсюда и результат.

Многие не любят вложенные запросы и часто это оправданно, все зависит от того как движок оптимизирует выполнение запроса.